# How do I enable logging for Spring Security?

Tags: debugging, spring-security

I am setting up Spring Security to handle logging users in. I have logged in as a user, and am taken to an Access Denied error page upon successful login. I don't know what roles my user has actually been assigned, or the rule that causes access to be denied, because I can't figure out how to enable debugging for the Spring Security library.

My security xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ... >
    <!-- security -->

    <security:debug/><!-- doesn't seem to be working -->

    <security:http auto-config="true">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/Admin**" access="hasRole('PROGRAMMER') or hasRole('ADMIN')"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/Load.do"
            default-target-url="/Admin.do?m=loadAdminMain"
            authentication-failure-url="/Load.do?error=true"
            username-parameter="j_username"
            password-parameter="j_password"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>
        <security:csrf/><!-- enable Cross Site Request Forgery protection -->
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="loginDataSource"
                users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password, active FROM userinformation WHERE username = ?"
                authorities-by-username-query="
                    SELECT ui.username, r.rolename 
                    FROM role r, userrole ur, userinformation ui 
                    WHERE ui.username=? 
                    AND ui.userinformationid = ur.userinformationid 
                    AND ur.roleid = r.roleid "
            />
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
</beans>
```

I've also tried adding `log4j.logger.org.springframework.security=DEBUG` to my log4j.properties

How can I get debug output for Spring Security?

Comment: check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840088/debugging-spring-configuration) If this can help you.

Comment: @pise can you add that as an answer (with at least a relevant excerpt/summary) so I can mark this as solved?

Comment: See the answer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840088/debugging-spring-configuration

Comment: Heh - tried to add it as an answer and SO converted it to a comment.

Answer (score 266):

Assuming you're using Spring Boot, another option is to put the following in your `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

This is the same for most other Spring modules as well.

If you're not using Spring Boot, try setting the property in your logging configuration, e.g. logback.

Here is the application.yml version as well:

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: DEBUG
```

Comment: Does this assume Spring Boot?

Comment: @JohnCamerin Yes, it does. Setting the log levels in `application.properties` is a Spring Boot feature. If you don't use Spring Boot you can set the log level `org.springframework.security` by other means (e.g. in your logback.xml).

Comment: For WebFlux it is not working: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5758

Comment: Add `org.springframework.web.cors` to enable Cors processor logs.

Answer (score 96):

You can easily enable debugging support using an option for the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    …
}
```

Comment: How about `EnableWebFluxSecurity`, it does not have the debug option

Comment: Ah, interesting. However, I have no experience with WebFlux.

Comment: is there a way to control this flag from application.properties

Answer (score 27):

Basic debugging using Spring's `DebugFilter` can be configured like this:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.debug(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's some pretty weak debug logging. It only prints out the request headers and "Security filter chain". Not useful at all when tracking down access problems.

Answer (score 9):

You can easily enable debugging support using an option for the `@EnableWebSecurity` annotation:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    // ...
}
```

If you need profile-specific control the in your *application-{profile}.properties* file

```ini
org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.debugEnabled=false
```

Get Detailed Post: http://www.bytefold.com/enable-disable-profile-specific-spring-security-debug-flag/

Answer (score 6):

**We can always check the registered filters inside Spring Security with the below configuration**

1. **@EnableWebSecurity(debug=true)** - We need to enable the debugging of the security details
2. Enable logging of the details by adding the below property in the *application.properties*   **logging.level.org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy=DEBUG**

**Below mentioning some of the internal filters of Spring Security that gets executed in the authentication flow:**

```
Security filter chain: [
  CharacterEncodingFilter
  WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter
  SecurityContextPersistenceFilter
  HeaderWriterFilter
  CsrfFilter
  LogoutFilter
  X509AuthenticationFilter
  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter
  RequestCacheAwareFilter
  SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter
  RememberMeAuthenticationFilter
  AnonymousAuthenticationFilter
  SessionManagementFilter
  ExceptionTranslationFilter
  FilterSecurityInterceptor
]
```

Answer (score 6):

Using Spring Boot with default spring security filters (without customizing anything, and without even setting debug in the `EnableWebSecurity` annotation), setting `TRACE` as the following `application.properties` shows:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE
```

Is enough for it to show in detail what filters are being called and what they are doing.

```
TRACE w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
TRACE w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
DEBUG w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Created HttpSession as SecurityContext is non-default
...
DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/product/productname01
TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (1/16)
...
TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/16)
DEBUG o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost/api/product/productname01
DEBUG o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
```

Versions:

```
Spring Framework Bom version 5.3.16
Spring Boot 2.6.4
Spring 5.3.16
Spring Security 5.6.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring security logging for webflux reactive apps is now available starting with version 5.4.0-M2 (as mentionned by [@bzhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/792883/bzhu) in comment [How do I enable logging for Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855252/how-do-i-enable-logging-for-spring-security#comment103321961_47729991))

Until this gets into a GA release, here is how to get this milestone release in gradle

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    if (!version.endsWith('RELEASE')) {
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
}

// Force earlier milestone release to get securing logging preview
// https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#getting-gradle-boot
// https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/8504
// https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/releases/tag/5.4.0-M2
ext['spring-security.version']='5.4.0-M2'
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

### 1. Set the logging level of Spring Security to `debug` or `trace`:

#### `application.yml`:

```yaml
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        security: debug # or trace
```

#### `application.properties`:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=debug
```

### 2. Enable the Spring Security debug mode

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> web.debug(true);
    }

}
```

or like this:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your application.properties:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.security=DEBUG
```

To know the roles of the user you can use the following code

```
@RestController
public class DemoController {
    //....
@GetMapping("/roles")
    public List<String> getUserRoles() {
        List<String> roles = rolesUser();
        return roles;
    }

    private List<String> rolesUser() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = (List<GrantedAuthority>) authentication.getAuthorities();
        List<String> roles = authorities.stream()
            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return roles;
    }
}
```