# Spring Boot Security OAuth2: WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter: 302 Redirect to /error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

Just the mere existence of an empty `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` ruins my app's OAuth2. 
I get

```
$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 27f9e2b7-4441-4c03-acdb-7e7dc358f783" -d '{"apiKey": "key", "tag": "tag"}' localhost:8080/isTagAvailable
HTTP/1.1 302
Location: http://localhost:8080/error
```

When I expect

```
$ curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer 27f9e2b7-4441-4c03-acdb-7e7dc358f783" -d '{"apiKey": "key", "tag": "tag"}' localhost:8080/isTagAvailable
HTTP/1.1 401

{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: 27f9e2b7-4441-4c03-acdb-7e7dc358f783"}
```

I have to comment out the *ENTIRE* class in order for the Oauth2 to work. Even just commenting `configure` method doesn't work. Why?

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/robots.txt").permitAll()
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/isTagAvailable").hasRole("USER")
//          .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .httpBasic().disable();
    }

}
```

[I learned how to add security logging](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855252/ddg#40950589), but [it didn't print out any useful information](https://gist.github.com/starrychloe/ee50eaf8b3defc39daa28384f3c88508).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw away `@EnableWebSecurity` and `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which just totally breaks the app. I thought they were required to get access to `HttpSecurity` which I thought I needed. I discovered this simple new class will solve the problem.

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    String[] ignoredPaths = new String[]{...};

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(ignoredPaths).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .httpBasic();   
    }
```