# Spring Security httpBasic() always showing unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, basic-authentication

I created the configuration class telling all requests must be authorized and setting `httpBasic()`:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

But despite that, the password generated when restarting the server seems to be always wrong and not authorizing. If I comment it out it will naturally allow access to an endpoint I have. What could be wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You need to tell use how are you storing the user/authorities information?

Comment: @macedonboy I am following a tutorial, and it is the generated `user` username and password that Spring created. No storage yet. This is what has been shown in the video but for me is not working.

Comment: The user information needs to be stored somewhere like InMemoryUserDetailsManager or some other Authentication manager

Comment: @macedonboy weird, it hasn't been done in the tutorial. If you'd like to see: https://youtu.be/her_7pa0vrg?t=1903

Comment: I am doing exactly the same thing he is but this @#$ is failing for me.

Comment: Seems like there's something missing from that video. Does [this](https://www.yawintutor.com/using-generated-security-password-spring-boot/) help?

Comment: No, it did not. I will recreate the project.

Comment: Ok, so it was something with the previous attempt. It was a user microservice connected with Zuul and etc. Probably something I haven't done to make it possible.

Comment: in the future i suggest you read up on how to debug in spring boot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47729991/1840146 will activate debuglogs that will tell you exactly what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Please attach to question also the controller and it's class, method level annotations.