# Spring Boot REST API POST 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, http-post

It is really strange and im sure im missing something. Here is my spring Security config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder())
                .usersByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username,password, enabled from user where username=?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
                        "select username, authority from authorities where username=?");

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http    .cors()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests() // authorize
                .antMatchers("/task/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/task/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated() // all requests are authenticated
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

So on *Postman* when i send a **GET** request i get **200 OK** status code. But when i hit a **POST** request i get **401 Unauthorized**

**UPDATE**
I have made the exact same POST request and i got **403 Forbiden** this time..... really strange

Also here is the **Controller** code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("task")
@CrossOrigin("http://localhost:3000")
public class TaskController {

    @Autowired
    private TaskRepo taskRepo;
    //private TaskDAO taskDAO;

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public List<Task> getTasks(){
        return taskRepo.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping("/create")
    public Task createTask(@RequestBody Task task) {
        Task savedTask = taskRepo.save(task);
        System.out.println("student id " + savedTask.getId());

        return savedTask;

    }

}
```

Comment: What about changing `                .antMatchers("/task/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,"/task/*").permitAll()` to `.antMatchers("/task/**").permitAll()`, notice the double `*` and removing the second line.

Comment: nothing changed, also it doesn't explain why ```GET``` works and not ```POST```. Even more strange is that now i get a 403 Forbidden error

Comment: Could you make a minimum reproducible sample? Then it can be debugged easier

Comment: Add `http.csrf().disable();` in configure method and try!

Comment: @Amitkumar it kind of worked, but know i get an exception cause it does't send the body, even tho i send a JSON from postman. I don't know if you can help me with that. But why ```http.csrf().disable();``` was needed only for post?

Comment: When you enable spring security via `@EnableWebSecurity` it internally enables CSRF as well. So, This has to be handled to prevent Forbidden errors.

Comment: the thing now is that i cannot send the Body from Post request. Server throws exception cause Body is full of ```null``` even tho i send a Body from Postman

Comment: Try `@PostMapping(path = "/create", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")`

Comment: it didn't work. I made a ```println()``` before throwing the exception and it's what i said. For some reason it don't get anything. 
Here is what the println printed ```Task{id=0, teachingHours=null, surveillanceHours=null, proofReading=null, isActive=false, isValidated=false, candidateId=null, supervisorId=null}
```

Comment: turn on spring security debugging https://stackoverflow.com/a/47729991/1840146 and it will tell you why you are getting the error messages

Comment: I have managed to overcome some problems. But know im facing a bigger one. Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65525635/how-to-save-entity-and-child-when-the-child-already-exists-in-spring-data-jpa-re .

Answer (score 7):

CSRF protection is enabled by default in the Java Security configuration, so you cannot access with modifying HTTP methods (POST, PUT, ...) from an external domain (like a web app or Postman). GET method is allowed by default.

You can disable CSRF protection with code similar to this:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .csrf().disable();
}
```

Thank you for Baeldung for teaching me that in [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf).

Comment: Using .csrf().disable(); Sonarqube alerts are insecure practice :(