# Why are my basic authentication credentials not accepted?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have a spring boot application where I want to secure different endpoints with different credentials.
I think roles are the best (only?) way to implement this and have written:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
  private static final String ROLE_1 = "role1";
  private static final String ROLE_2 = "role2";

  @Autowired
  private MyBasicAuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

  @Override
  protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .withUser("user1").password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass")).roles(ROLE_1)
        .and()
        .withUser("user2").password("user2Pass").roles(ROLE_2);
    }
  
  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/endpoint1").hasRole(ROLE_1)
                                             .antMatchers("/endpoint2").hasRole(ROLE_2)
                                             .antMatchers("/").permitAll().and().httpBasic()
                                             .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);

    http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
  }
  
  @Bean 
  public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { 
      return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); 
  }
}
```

But when I call either endpoint (with the credentials from `configure`) I get `401 Unauthorized`. Why are the credentials I specify in `configure` not accepted?

Comment: also to find out such stuff learn how to activate debug logs in spring security https://stackoverflow.com/a/47729991/1840146

Answer (score 0):

Because you are telling spring that the generated hash is the password. And not your password, so it gets double hashed.

```
.password(passwordEncoder().encode("user1Pass"))
```

if you look in the [official documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-inmemory) it shows you how you should construct your user, you should be using the `withDefaultPasswordEncoder` and spring will hash the password for you.

```
User user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
  .username("user")
  .password("password")
  .roles("user")
  .build();
System.out.println(user.getPassword());
```

Remember that setting up users this way should only be done for tests, and never production, thats why `withDefaultPasswordEncoder` is deprecated in the official api.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a closer look at this later. Upfront: I don't use a hash for user2 and that doesn't work either, so I think there is something else wrong