# External keycloak server and Spring boot app behind reverse proxy - redirect to root context after success login

Tags: spring-boot, redirect, keycloak, reverse-proxy

My spring boot service is working behind reverse proxy and secured by external keycloak server.

After successful login at Keycloak server it redirects me to my service and then I get redirect to root of context path instead of initial url.

So request chain is looks like:

initial url: `http://~HOSTNAME~/~SERVICE-NAME~/rest/info/654321`

and redirects:

`http://~HOSTNAME~/~SERVICE-NAME~/rest/sso/login`

`https://ext-keycloak.server/auth/realms/test/protocol/openid-connect/auth?response_type=code&client_id=dev&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F~HOSTNAME~%2F~SERVICE-NAME~%2Frest%2Fsso%2Flogin&state=60ebad0d-8c68-43cd-9461&login=true&scope=openid`

`http://~HOSTNAME~/~SERVICE-NAME~/rest/sso/login?state=60ebad0d-8c68-43cd-9461&session_state=074aaa0d-4f72-440e&code=a8c92c50-70f8-438c-4fe311f0b3b6.074aaa0d-440e-8726.8166b689-bbdd-493a-8b8f`

`http://~HOSTNAME~/~SERVICE-NAME~/rest/` - I have no handlers here and getting error.

First problem was that application generated wrong redirect uri for keycloak. All services are in kubernetes cluster and have urls like: `http://~HOSTNAME~/~SERVICE-NAME~/rest` (where '/rest' is context path).

**~SERVICE-NAME~** part is used to locate service in cluster and application gets request without this prefix. But proxy adds header **X-Original-Request** with original url and I decided to use it (unfortunately I can't change configuration of proxy and keycloak servers). I made filter to use header value to generate correct redirect uri by copy-pasting from Spring's `org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter`. Now it generates correct redirect_uri but I'm getting wrong redirect at the end as described above.

How can I get redirect to initial page in this case?

**Spring security config:**

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = KeycloakSecurityComponents.class)
public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final PermissionConfig permissionConfig;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(PermissionConfig permissionConfig) {
        this.permissionConfig = permissionConfig;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
        keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(new NullAuthoritiesMapper());
        auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver KeycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
        return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        super.configure(http);
        var urlRegistry = http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/actuator/**")
                .permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/info/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority(permissionConfig.getRoles().toArray(new String[0]));
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<OriginalUriHeaderFilter> originalUriHeaderFilter() {
        OriginalUriHeaderFilter filter = new OriginalUriHeaderFilter();
        FilterRegistrationBean<OriginalUriHeaderFilter> registration = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(filter);
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.ASYNC, DispatcherType.ERROR);
        registration.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

**spring keycloak config** (yaml)

```
keycloak:
  auth-server-url: 'https://ext-keycloak.server/auth/'
  realm: test
  ssl-required: NONE
  resource: dev
  credentials:
    secret: 'hex-value'
  confidential-port: 0
  disable-trust-manager: true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uh, the problem was with service prefix not with Keycloak.

When I tryed to get page Spring set JSESSIONID cookie with path=**/rest**, stored request to session and redirected me to Keycloak. After login Spring couldn't find session and redirected me to root context because browser didn't provide JSESSIONID cookie for path **/~SERVICE-NAME~/rest** !!

By default Spring sets cookie path=`server.servlet.contextPath`. All I've done just added cookie path to application.yaml:

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    contextPath: /rest
    session:
      cookie:
        path: /
```

[Spring Server Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#common-application-properties-server)

[Spring DebugFilter is quite useful thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40950589/7589406)

Answer (score 1):

For future searchs, an another approach is to use the **KeycloakCookieBasedRedirect.createCookieFromRedirectUrl** method, that includes a cookie for keycloak redirect.