# Spring Boot Form Login Custom UserDetailsService authorisation not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

I am a beginner at Spring Boot and really struggling to get this. I am not finding Spring boot's security API very intuitive at all, but I'm trying to get it.

I am going to use MySql with JPA to get Users from the Database,
But initially just to ensure that the security scaffolding works, I am just hard coding a User From Employee Details Service.

After a lot of trouble, I have managed to get the basic Authentication to work, but the Authorisation is not working.
I have edited the question to reflect the basic issue:

I am aware that there are other questions out there before people mark this as duplicate, I have gone through all of them, they all respond with basic answers that I think are already working in my app.

At the end
/home path is for home method,
/mama path is for role mama

Here is the code:

```
//AppSecurityConfig.java
package com.straightwalls.absencemanagement.config;

import com.straightwalls.absencemanagement.service.EmployeeDetailsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import 
     org.springframework.security.config
    .annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import 
    org.springframework.security.config
    .annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;

import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

   protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    //Disabled for development
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/mama").hasRole("MAMA")
            .antMatchers("/home").hasAnyRole("ROLE_HEAD", "ROLE_MAMA")
            .and()
            .formLogin();
}

    @Bean
    /*
    * Returning no op password encoder for now,
    * as we are not encoding passwords as no registration
    * implemented for Prototype. We would need to add the users from a separate service. W
    *
    * */
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}



//EmployeeDetailsService
package com.straightwalls.absencemanagement.service;

import com.straightwalls.absencemanagement.model.Employee;
import com.straightwalls.absencemanagement.model.Role;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class EmployeeDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {


    @Override
    
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
                         throws UsernameNotFoundException {
         
    if (!username.equals("Mama")){
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
            "You got the wrong Username, should be mama"
        );
    }

    Employee employee = new Employee();
    Role role = new Role();
    role.setName("HEAD");
    employee
        .setUsername(username)
        .setPassword("1234")
        .setRole(role);

    return new EmployeePrincipal(employee);
    }
}


    //EmployeePrincipal.java
    package com.straightwalls.absencemanagement.service;
    
    import com.straightwalls.absencemanagement.model.Employee;
    import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
    import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
    
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.Collection;
    
    
    public class EmployeePrincipal implements UserDetails {

    private Employee employee;
    
    //Added another default Constructor, incase
    public EmployeePrincipal(){

    }

    public EmployeePrincipal(Employee employee){
        this.employee = employee;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_HEAD"));
        //return Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + employee.getRole().getName()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return employee.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return employee.getUsername();
    }

    /*
    * Methods below are the rubbish methods, we keep as true for now
    *
    * */
    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}



//Login.java
package com.straightwalls.absencemanagement.api;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class LoginApi {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "Straight Walls absence management!";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "Welcome to Home!";
    }

    /**
    * This method can be deleted in the end
    *
    */
    @RequestMapping("/mama")
    public String roleTest(){
        return "This end point is only for Mama!";
    }

}

//Employee.java
package com.straightwalls.absencemanagement.model;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Fetch;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

@Entity
public class Employee {

    @Id
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String startDate;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "roleId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Role role;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "departmentId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Department department;

    public Employee(){

    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public Employee setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public Employee setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public Employee setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        return this;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public Employee setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
        return this;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public Employee setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
        return this;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }


    public Employee setStartDate(LocalDate startDate) {
      this.startDate =   
      startDate.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
      return this;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public Employee setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
        return this;
    }

    public Department getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }

    public Employee setDepartment(Department department) {
        this.department = department;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Server Logs:
2021-04-21 07:42:12.151  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] traightWallsAbsenceManagementApplication : Starting StraightWallsAbsenceManagementApplication using Java 16 on Peshotans-MacBook-Air.local with PID 10370 (/Users/peshotanpavri/java/IdeaProjects/StraightWallsAbsenceManagement/target/classes started by peshotanpavri in /Users/peshotanpavri/java/IdeaProjects/StraightWallsAbsenceManagement)
2021-04-21 07:42:12.154  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] traightWallsAbsenceManagementApplication : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-21 07:42:12.254  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-04-21 07:42:12.255  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-04-21 07:42:14.065  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2021-04-21 07:42:14.203  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 113 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
2021-04-21 07:42:15.235  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-04-21 07:42:15.253  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-21 07:42:15.253  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.45]
2021-04-21 07:42:15.404  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-21 07:42:15.405  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3147 ms
2021-04-21 07:42:15.642  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2021-04-21 07:42:16.670  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2021-04-21 07:42:16.743  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2021-04-21 07:42:16.859  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.30.Final
2021-04-21 07:42:17.121  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-21 07:42:17.327  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2021-04-21 07:42:18.359  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2021-04-21 07:42:18.383  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2021-04-21 07:42:18.458  WARN 10370 --- [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2021-04-21 07:42:18.737  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@7e4d562b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@657e3908, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@484dbda9, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@358c0253, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@4596a3b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@6dceb9b9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@697f408b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@6a227727, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@166853dc, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@185f798b, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@7f7692e4, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5406fd30, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@66387082, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@44bb34bf, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@768269d7]
2021-04-21 07:42:18.981  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-21 07:42:19.784  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-04-21 07:42:19.835  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-21 07:42:19.851  INFO 10370 --- [  restartedMain] traightWallsAbsenceManagementApplication : Started StraightWallsAbsenceManagementApplication in 8.486 seconds (JVM running for 10.642)
2021-04-21 07:42:45.273  INFO 10370 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-21 07:42:45.275  INFO 10370 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-21 07:42:45.300  INFO 10370 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 24 ms

I am logging in with a dummy role HEAD.
So I should be able to access: /, /home but not /mama
I cant access /home, even though the role has been properly defined

In my base package, I have the following packages:
config: With this config file,
model: All entities
api: Controllers
repository: Repositories (Not used yet)
service: Where I have EmployeeDetailsService & EmployeeDetails class

Any advice would be greatly appreciated as I am expecting this to work, but its just not throwing any errors and just constantly saying bad credentials even though I have put the username Mama and password Mama and tried with NoOpPasswordEncoder

Comment: have you created a class implementing `UserDetailsService` to override the `loadUserByUsername()` ?  Please refer this https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-security

Comment: Thank you for that. I am going through the example. Yes I have done this EmployeeDetailsService class, it is there in the code example. I have tried everything. The in memory woks fine, but that is not what I want

Comment: autowire `EmployeeDetailsService` rather than `UserDetailsService `

Comment: also i was able to find  an example https://github.com/anushshetty1234/BookStore/blob/master/BookStore/src/main/java/com/bookstore/config/SecurityConfig.java

Comment: can you please run your application with debug logs active, start it up, do your request and update your question with the logs. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47729991/1840146

Comment: Okay I will run the application with the logs, I tried auto wire EmployeeDetailsService, same thing

Comment: I managed to get the basic security to work, now its about the Authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to fix this by cleaning up the code and making a few changes to the grantedAuthorities method, which didn't need the ROLE_

Also changed hasRole, hasAnyRole with hasAuthority and hasAnyAuthority by eliminating the ROLE_
Not sure why but it works now.

Also the API is a lot simpler to understand now

Here is the updated code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class AppSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);

        /*auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("appuser").password("1234").roles("HEAD")
                .and()
                .withUser("Mama").password("Mama").roles("MAMA");*/

    }

    @Override
    /*
    * Now we have learnt the basics of Spring Security & Authrization method is completed.
    * Lets fix Authentication first!
    * Got it to work with hasAuthority & hasAnyAuthority but not with roles, not sure why, but it works atm
    *
    * */
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        //Disabled for development
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/mama").hasAuthority("MAMA")
                .antMatchers("/home").hasAnyAuthority("HEAD", "MAMA")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()

                .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/")
                    .defaultSuccessUrl("/home");
    }

    @Bean
    /*
    * Returning no op password encoder for now, as we are not encoding passwords as no registration
    * implemented for Prototype. We would need to add the users from a separate service. W
    *
    * */
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder(){
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

}


//EmployeeDetailsService.java
@Service
public class EmployeeDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {


    @Override
    /*
    * First, we are testing the Employee details service, independent of the Database, just to make sure we have this part working,
    * For the purpose of these prototypes, we wont use password encoder because we are not registering,
    *
    * */
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        if (!username.equals("Mama")){
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("You got the wrong Username, should be mama");
        }

        Employee employee = new Employee();
        Role role = new Role();
        role.setName("HEAD");
        employee
                .setUsername(username)
                .setPassword("1234")
                .setRole(role);

        return new EmployeePrincipal(employee);

    }
}


    //EmployeePrincipal.java
    public class EmployeePrincipal implements UserDetails {
    
        private Employee employee;
    
    
        public EmployeePrincipal(Employee employee){
            this.employee = employee;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(employee.getRole().getName()));
            return  authorities;
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getPassword() {
            return employee.getPassword();
        }
    
        @Override
        public String getUsername() {
            return employee.getUsername();
        }
    
        /*
        * Methods below are the rubbish methods, we keep as true for now
        *
        * */
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
            return true;
        }
    
        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled() {
            return true;
        }
    }


@RestController
public class LoginApi {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){
        return "Index"
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "Home!";
    }

    /*
    * This method can be deleted in the end
    * */
    @RequestMapping("/mama")
    public String roleTest(){
        return "This end point is only for Mama!";
    }

}
```