# How can I enable logging for Spring Security in Grails 2.2.3?

Tags: spring-security, grails-2.0

How do I enable logging for Spring Security in grails 2.2.3 ?

I what to see the full log of spring security.
I trying to handle it on onAuthenticationFailure method but did not worked

```
public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response,
            final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        if (SpringSecurityUtils.isAjax(request)) {
            saveException(request, exception);
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, _ajaxAuthenticationFailureUrl);
        }
        else {
            super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
        }

    }
```

Comment: one solution is using  this code in log4j of config.groovy  grails app
log4j = {
   
     root {
        debug()
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could set the log level to debug for root in your project so it would log everything or you could set it only for springsecurity. try this link :
[How do I enable logging for Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855252/how-do-i-enable-logging-for-spring-security)