# Spring boot Security custom filter does not invoke

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices, spring-cloud-config

I am developing an application following microservice architecture using spring boot 3.2.0 and Java 17. I have one service - `AuthService` for authentication purpose. Users' login request will be routed by API gateway to `AuthService` and get a **JWT** token upon providing valid user credentials.

Now, user has a valid **JWT** token. By putting this token in request header in `Bearer token` format user can make http request to any other services (i.e. employeeService, hospitalService..; i will refer these services as `OtherService`). I don't want to burden `OtherService` with the token validation codes. Rather, there is an API endpoint at `AuthService` -> `/auth/validate`. This endpoint will validate the jwt token and returns a cusotm `UserDetails` object.

In a nutshell, the workflow is something like this - if user want to see list of employees, first user will provide username, password. This will be validated by `AuthService` and returns a **JWT** token. then, with this token user will make request to employeeService. There will be filter in `EmployeeService` which will check if there is any Authoriztion token in the request header and make rest call to `AuthService` to get a **UserDetail** object from it.

[P.S. I am new to spring security; I am not sure if this approach is ideal or not]

Bellow, I am providing the code portion of `EmployeeService`.

1. **ApplicationSecurity**

```
@RefreshScope
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationSecurity {

    private final AppSecurityFilter appSecurityFilter;


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        return http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(appSecurityFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/health")
                        .permitAll()
                        .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated())
                .build();
    }
}
```

Note: I have not defined any `AuthenticationManager` or `AuthenticationProvider` `bean` here since I am not validating or getting user object from the db here in `EmployeeService` rather calling `AuthService` to do this from the `AppSecurityFilter`.

**2. AppSecurityFilter**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
public class AppSecurityFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private static String AUTH_SERVER_VALIDATE_TOKEN_URL = "http://AUTH-SERVICE/auth/api/v1/validate";

    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String header = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);

        if (isEmpty(header) || !header.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        ResponseEntity<AuthResponseDto> authResponse = // get userDetails form authService via restTeamplate post call

        UserResponseDto user = authResponse.getBody().getUserResponseDto();

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user,
                        null,
                        user.getAuthorities()
                )
        );

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

So, the issue I am facing is; even though I set Authorization token in the request header; `EmployeeService` application redirects the request to spring's default login page. Furthermore, the `AppSecurityFilter` never invokes.

What I am missing here, and what are the necessary steps to make this work?

Comment: what you are missing is that you should not use JWTs as sessions, there is a reason to why that type of filter doesnt exist in spring security per default. Because it is not recommended to hand out JWTs to browsers.

Comment: @Toerktumlare, are referring to adding - `http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS));` ?

Comment: can you please guide me through a proper approach according to the scenario stated above? about the log, there is no error in the console, and I am not sure what to look into there. Though I see the custom filter being added in the filter chain. I think, spring security needs AuthenticationManager bean to be setup.

Comment: stack overflow is not a forum were we "guide" ppl, its a Q/A site were you ask one well defined question and get one well defined answer. I suggest that you start spending time with reading the spring security documentation. A simple google search https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855252/how-do-i-enable-logging-for-spring-security please start reading the spring security documentation before resorting to asking here on stack overflow. If the docs are unclear, then ask about the docs and what is unclear and we will guide you.

Comment: I think my question was/is clear and well defined. For your clarification, *I wanted to know why my customFilter wasn't invoked*.

Comment: and my effort was not to answer your question thats why this is a comment. My effort was to point out that what you are doing is _bad practice_ so that you are aware of it. Building custom security solutions is _always bad practice_.

Comment: All I needed was, someone to point me out to `RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter`. That could have saved me a two days search time. I think that's why people come here.

Comment: reason ppl come to stack overflow is to get correct answers, not just any answer. `and get a JWT token upon providing valid user credentials` is called a _password credentials grant_ and is flagged as *MUST NOT USE* by the best practices standards stipulated by ietf (the creators of the oauth2 standard) https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics-13#section-3.4 so the correct answer here is that this type of login should not be built, as it is insecure. Thats why this type of login does not exist in spring security.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As @FabioFranco mentioned, I didn't miss anything in the security configuration. The problem was occurring due to `@RefreshScope` annotation added in the `ApplicationSecurity` class. *(p.s. I didn't add this annotation in the question at first thinking that this wasn't related to the issue)*.

Adding my findings here if someone stumble upon this type of issue in future.

After investing the log, I found that if `@RefreshScope` is added then there were two separate logs of `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` at the time of application startup -

```
line1: o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Will secure any request with [
    DisableEncodeUrlFilter, 
    WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter,
    SecurityContextHolderFilter,
    HeaderWriterFilter,
    LogoutFilter,
    AppSecurityFilter,  <------------------- my custom filter added
    RequestCacheAwareFilter,
    SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,
    AnonymousAuthenticationFilter,
    SessionManagementFilter,
    ExceptionTranslationFilter,
    AuthorizationFilter
]

line2: o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Will secure any request with [
    DisableEncodeUrlFilter,
    WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter,
    SecurityContextHolderFilter,
    HeaderWriterFilter,
    CorsFilter,
    CsrfFilter,
    LogoutFilter,
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter,
    DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter,
    DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter,
    BasicAuthenticationFilter,
    RequestCacheAwareFilter,
    SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,
    AnonymousAuthenticationFilter,
    ExceptionTranslationFilter,
    AuthorizationFilter
]
```

As you can see, the immediate second line of the log doesn't have the custom filter I have configured.

If I removed the `@RefreshScope` annotation from the class, there was only one line of log printed for `DefaultSecurityFilterChain` -

```
DefaultSecurityFilterChain : Will secure any request with [
    DisableEncodeUrlFilter,
    WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter,
    SecurityContextHolderFilter,
    HeaderWriterFilter,
    LogoutFilter,
    AppSecurityFilter,  <------------------ my custom filter
    RequestCacheAwareFilter,
    SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,
    AnonymousAuthenticationFilter,
    SessionManagementFilter,
    ExceptionTranslationFilter,
    AuthorizationFilter
]
```

And by removing `@RefreshScope` from the `ApplicationSecurity` class, everything works as expected.

Why I added `@RefreshScope` at the first place? *I was reading some properties form the ConfigServer.*

Why adding `@RefreshScope` makes spring security to fallback to default configuration? *I haven't figured that out yet.*

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your service has the role of a resource server in an oauth2 workflow. Is that correct? If so, I'd recommend following the instructions on the [official spring security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/resource-server/jwt.html) on how to authorize resources with a bearer token.

Furthermore, the way spring security docs recommend us to add filters to the security filter chain has a [little caveat](https://arc.net/l/quote/begpcezb) you should follow.

Also at a first glance I couldn't see what you are missing, but if you provide a bit more context, such as spring boot version as well as configuration files, maybe it's possible to provide more helpul insights.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details if it helps you to grasp the problem I am facing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).