# Turn on DEBUG logging for org.springframework.integration

Tags: xml, eclipse, spring, debugging, spring-integration

How to turn on **DEBUG logging for org.springframework.integration** in eclipse, I am very new in spring integration, I want to debug my spring integration xml file content because Http request is not working.

Comment: Have you try this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840088/debugging-spring-configuration

Comment: Thanks i will try that out .

Comment: Also see the [spring framework logging documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html#overview-logging) to assist with configuring a logging subsystem of your choice (log4j, logback etc).

Answer (score 1):

Spring integration has an additional flag `@EnableIntegrationManagement(defaultLoggingEnabled = "true")`