# spring security return 403, logging not working

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, http-status-code-403

I am not able to make Spring Security work. I tested my application with `security:user-service` and it works perfectly well. However when I replace the

```
<security:user-service>
    <security:user name="XX" password="XX" authorities="ROLE_EDITOR" />                
</security:user-service>
```

with

```
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider>
        <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" 
            users-by-username-query="SELECT name as username, password, 1 as enabled FROM cuser WHERE name=?;"
            authorities-by-username-query="SELECT u.name as username, r.name as authority FROM cuser u join cuserrole ur on ur.iduser=u.id join crole r on r.id=ur.idrole where u.name=?;" />
    </security:authentication-provider>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

I can no longer make it work. Keep getting 403 response from the server. I ran the queries on my db and they return the expected values.

I am not able to make the logging work either, so am finding it hard to debug what is really happening behind the scenes. 
I did read similar problems on SO

[How do I enable logging for Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30855252/how-do-i-enable-logging-for-spring-security)

[Debugging Spring configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7840088/debugging-spring-configuration)

Tried the solutions nut still the logging doesn't work. If someone has any idea, your help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Can't believe it..

Spring requires ROLE_ prefix for security to work.because of this i was getting 403.

Comment: Could someone tell me why ROLE_ prefix though? thanks Can't I use my handcrafted role name ?

Answer (score 0):

Class [RoleVoter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/access/vote/RoleVoter.java) has a setter for property `rolePrefix`

```
public class RoleVoter implements AccessDecisionVoter<Object> {
    // ~ Instance fields
    // ================================================================================================

    private String rolePrefix = "ROLE_";

    // ~ Methods
    // ========================================================================================================

    public String getRolePrefix() {
        return rolePrefix;
    }

    /**
     * Allows the default role prefix of <code>ROLE_</code> to be overridden. May be set
     * to an empty value, although this is usually not desirable.
     *
     * @param rolePrefix the new prefix
     */
    public void setRolePrefix(String rolePrefix) {
        this.rolePrefix = rolePrefix;
}
```

So you could just set this property in a RoleVoter and then set into the AccessDecissionManager and configure it as the access-decission-manager-ref in spring security http configuration