# Overriding properties defined in custom spring-boot-starter doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

On a classpath of my custom spring boot starter `some-service-spring-boot-starter` there is a `application.yaml` with bunch of default properties (such as `server.port` and others). I expected that in consumer app's `application.yaml` those properties can be overridden, but that's not the case - it looks like starter's config takes precedence over whatever is defined in the application itself.
Is this an expected behaviour or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Enable trace to get more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52455066/2834978